# How to do a slow CSS transition to opacity = 1, and a fast/immediate transition to opacity = 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
.item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 6s;
}
```

I'm using JS to set the opacity from 0 to 1 and vise-versa.

Is there a way in CSS to make the opacity transition from 0-1 last 6 seconds, but have the transition from 1-0 last 0 seconds?

I suppose I could set the transition property in JS, but is there a way to produce this behavior with CSS?

Comment: You would have to define the animation's key frames and their durations. `@keyframes` See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes, alternatively you could use 2 different CSS classes one called `styleVisible` and the other called `styleHidden` with the timings set the way you want on each style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transition property in the two different classes where you would be setting different opacity.

```css
.itemHidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 6s;
}

.itemShown {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

Comment: I tested this method and found it did not work, unfortunately. The opacity changes without any transition at all.

Comment: It works for me, https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-villani-0jc78

Comment: You're right. There was something else complicating matters, which I sorted out and this method does indeed work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I like Vijay's answer since it is a lot shorter and sweeter.  However, I think it is worth seeing how you could create an animation with keyframes since that was also mentioned in one of the comments.  An example using keyframes would be something like this:

```
.item {
  animation-name: demo-animation;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

@keyframes demo-animation
{
  25% {
    opacity: .25;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: .75;
  }
  99.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
    100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: So this will have the opacity change pretty evenly.  However, you could change the opacity values to fade in faster or slower.  You also don't need to use the exact percentages that I did.